# Migrating from Swift 3.2 to Swift 4 I get an error using autosavesInPlace

Tags: swift, macos, migration, nsdocument

In a macOS project I use autosavesInPlace in this way:

```
import Cocoa

class Document: NSDocument {

    override class func autosavesInPlace() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

This worked until the project was in Swift 3.2 but when updating the project in Swift 4, I get this error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Swift 4 `autosavesInPlace` is a property (not a function), so you should override in this way:

```
class Document: NSDocument {
   override class var autosavesInPlace: Bool {
     return true
   }
}
```